# How to bind data to sub properties of a property defined in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have the following **xaml** which is not working:

```
    ...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrganisationTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserStatusTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=profile.name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>     
    ...

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Home">
            <ListBox Name="UserStatus" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserStatusTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding UserStatus}" Margin="0,0,0,96" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

I have the following **viewmodel**:

```
public class Sections
{
    public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }
}

class DashboardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Sections sections = new Sections();

    private OrganisationRepository organisationRepository { get; set; }
    private UserRepository userRepository { get; set; }

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        LoadOrganisationSection();
        LoadHomeSection();
    }

    ...

    private async void LoadHomeSection()
    {
        userRepository = new UserRepository();
        sections.UserStatus = await userRepository.GetStatus();
        UserStatus = null;
    }

    #region properties
    public UserStatus UserStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return sections.UserStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sections.UserStatus != value)
            {
                //LoginCredentials.Username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler tempEvent = PropertyChanged;

        if (tempEvent != null)
        {
            // property changed
            tempEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Inside *LoadHomeSection*, the *section.UserStatus* has a property filled up (I have debugged so it's definetly there) with the route: *section.UserStatus.profile.name* and obviously this gets reflected in the property exposed to the viewmodel: *UserStatus.profile.name*

**How do I access a sub property in my xaml?**

I have other properties that work if the property to access is straight there (see *OrganisationTemplate*)

I have seen other posts but I can't get their versions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's because you can't use a single item in a ListBox... duhhh:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Home">
                <TextBlock Name="UserStatus" Text="{Binding UserStatus.profile.name}" />
                <!--<ListBox Name="UserStatus" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserStatusTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding UserStatus}" Margin="0,0,0,96" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>-->
            </phone:PanoramaItem>
```